# Count number of unique rows Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

Hi I have a set of data which consists of a year and string. I would like to count the number of times each string occurs within each year. For example,

1997 string
1997 string
1997 string
1997 key
1998 string
1998 key
1998 key

and I want it to return

1997 string 3
1997 key 1
1998 string 1
1998 key 2

I'm confused about if I should format these as a table or a cell array when exporting from a large csv file of around 7,000 values and how to create a new table which has the unique values and the number of times they appeared?

Comment: After you **im**port this data into MATLAB, how does it appear? Two vectors? Cell array? Table? Structure? Please specify this (or better yet, provide code that creates sample data) to get better answers. This can probably be answered with some combination of `unique(A,'rows')` and `accumarray`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of unique and histcounts.

```
strings = {'1997 string'
     '1997 string'
     '1997 string'
     '1997 key'
     '1998 string'
     '1998 key'
     '1998 key'};
[uniqueStrings, ~, uniquePositions] = unique(strings);
uniqueCounts = histcounts(uniquePositions)';
[uniqueStrings, num2cell(uniqueCounts)]
```

Comment: would it be possible to do this while leaving the "1997" and the "string" sections separate (two different columns of the table)?

Comment: I'm not sure what you want. Please edit your example to show your new request, or ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the data being in a table I think this will work:

```
data = {'1997', 'string'; '1997', 'string'; '1997', 'string'; '1997', 'key'; '1998', 'string'; '1998', 'key'; '1998', 'key'};

data_table = cell2table(data);
[unique_data,cnt] = unique(data_table,'rows');

data_table_combined = strcat(data_table.data1,'_',data_table.data2);
unique_combined = strcat(unique_data.data1,'_',unique_data.data2);

for i = 1:length(unique_combined)
    b = strfind(cell(data_table_combined),char(unique_combined(i)));
    count(i) = sum(cell2mat(b));
end

count_table = table(count');
NT = [unique_data,count_table]
```

It produces this table:

NT =

```
data1      data2      Var1
______    ________    ____

'1997'    'key'       1   
'1997'    'string'    3   
'1998'    'key'       2   
'1998'    'string'    1
```

You can use table2cell(NT) to make it into a cell array as well.

Hope this helps.